# I lost my XP partition when installing Ubuntu alongside Win 7

Tags: installation

I had a dual boot system with XP and Win 7. I installed Ubuntu alongside win 7.

Now I dont see my XP option when I reboot just a red sceen with Ubuntu and win 7 options.

In win7 I see the XP partition is still there and active. How can I get to it? How can I add it to the red screen with Ubuntu and Win 7 so I have a 3 option boot?

Comment: Do you have an installation CD of Ubuntu ?! - you need this for the rescue mode. - Then I can tell you what to do.

Comment: You can boot too - with a supergrub-CD. With supergrub you could boot into installed Ubuntu and from there repair the installed grub resp. modify the grub.conf files. - but for this we would need first the output of: fdisk -l (in terminal of installed ubuntu).

Comment: THanks for responding and sorry for delay-been on holiday! I have an installation CD with Ubuntu 12.10 on it. Thats what I used to do the side by side win 7 and Ubuntu. I think I used win 7 to shrink the partition to free up space for Ubuntu. It all works great-I have ubuntu and win 7 but my XP partition doesnt show in the boot screen-just Ubuntu, mem check and win 7. However in win 7 and Ubuntu I see the XP partition so I guess it is still there and healthy but cant be accessed.

Comment: hmmm- win7 and Ubuntu are 64-Bit in your machine ?! and XP is 32-Bit in your machine ?! - or altogether are 32-Bit then ?! simply try supergrub-CD in case there is still trouble - otherwise do following : ... then I would install grub > 2.00 - probably your grub is < 2.00 like grub 1.98 or grub 1.99 ? - also try to use package-manager for to remove grub completely and install resp. re-install then grub2.

Comment: Thank you for responding.The OS are all 32 bit. I set up dual booting with GPartED and still see XP & 7 as disk icons in Ubuntu and XP as a partition in win 7. Unfortunately I dont understand what supergrub is or anything to do with Linux!

Comment: ignore this with supergrub - I thought that you are not able to log into your main ubuntu ?! If you are able to log in - and if it is not Ubuntu 13.04, instead it is Version < 13.04 - then you should get sure, that you have grub2 installed and not grub-version like 1.99 or 1.98 - anyway ... support for XP expires soon, so take over your data (e.g. for Libreoffice) to Ubuntu or to Win7 via usb-stick.

Comment: The Linux is version 13.04. The win 7 and Linux are working well but my XP Partition, though visible in Linux and 7, doesn't show up in the boot menu. I just see Ubuntu, mem test, mem test, Win 7. What I would like is to be able to add XP to the boot menu.

Comment: Also I just realised when i select win 7 it takes me to the windows boot screen (black and white) and there is the XP option which is selectable and loads! So I havent lost it it is just under the win 7 choice in Ubuntu boot screen. I am nevertheless going to try and get all 3 options together as suggested by DSCHINN1001 (THank You)

Answer (score 0):

Does this link help ?

https://superuser.com/questions/401331/how-to-add-windows-7-to-grub-menu

You need to edit file of grub.conf - before that you need to know the partition where XP lies. In your case you can still boot into Ubuntu-System ? - So boot normal into Ubuntu-System - from there you edit then the grub-files as described here with help of terminal and gedit. -

You can find the partition out in terminal with:

> sudo fdisk -l

The file grub.conf lies in the directory of /boot on your partition where 13.04 is installed.

BUT now this - assumed

> sudo fdisk -l

is not recognizing XP on the first partition... I guess XP was the first installation of all installations in this case, then

With

> sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg

we edit this file and make after this located entries below :

> BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom
>
> This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
>
> menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
>
> the 'exec tail' line above.
>
> END /etc/grub.d/40_custom

is following to add :

> title WindowsXP
>
> rootnoverify (hd0,0)
>
> makeactive
>
> chainloader +1

hd0,0 is for the partition where Windows XP as first installation of all systems lies.
chainloader +1 is setting Windows XP as first option in the grub menue to choose.

Don't forget in the end to do in terminal :

> sudo update-grub2

reboot your machine.

Let me know - if this helped and if red screen disappeared ?

Comment: Thanks for this. I am going to try the steps you have so generously set out for me above.

Comment: Dear dschinn1001 I tried the edit. I found the file grub.cfg and added in the lines as written in you suggestion. The problem came when closing and saving the file. I tried save as and could not overwrite the file grib.cfg. I tried to save as grub2.cfg and again got could not save the file (you do not have the permissions necessary to save the file)

Comment: I managed to save the grub.cfg file but when I ran the update grub2 command it just showed up Ubuntu, mem test, memtes, win 7 as before. On restart these are the choices as before. I can get to XP through the win 7 choice so although this is a bit clumbsy it is a work around.

Comment: @Gary - (for write permission) did you do: sudo gedit ??? (in terminal) - then you should have write permission if not - check with: ls -al /boot/grub/grub.cfg the permissions. They are set to 444 - so you need to do: sudo chmod 757 /boot/grub/grub.cfg - then edit this file - when finish then do: sudo chmod 444 /boot/grub/grub.cfg - after that then : sudo update-grub2

Comment: Thanks for your patience.Typing sudo gedit in terminal window asks for my password then says       IBUS-WARNING The owner of home/gary/.config/tbus/bus is not root! Maybe I need to get back like in DOS you type CD \ and the command prompt then goes back to the root of C?

Comment: Maybe I need to get back like in DOS you type CD \ and the command prompt then goes back to the root of C? My terminal has gary@gary-NF110-NF210-NF310:~$

Comment: @Gary - have to think about... please wait.

Comment: @Gary don't confuse this - you are always user, and some directories may only be changed by root, so your system asks (to become root) for your password to change in this case /home/gary/.config - when you type: cd /  then you are in in the root-directory of your Ubuntu-system - but this is not necessary here. Problem is here the label of WindowsXP for grub2. Question to you : Is installation of Ubuntu 64Bit or 32Bit ? - WinXP is 32Bit ...

Comment: @Gary - It is something to be changed about a label of WindowsXP - but I found only different hints - so would try then boot-repair with a tool described like here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @Gary - do NOT create a new partition table !